# How to delete all records using go-pg package

Tags: postgresql, go

I use [go-pg](https://github.com/go-pg/pg) package to work with postgres. I have the following model:

```golang
type DataItem struct{
    tableName struct{} `pg:"some_table"`

    SomeID    string    `pg:"some_id,pk"`
    SomeData  string    `pg:"some_data"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `pg:"updated_at"`
}
```

At some point I need to delete all records from the table. So I do:

```golang
package storage

import (
    "github.com/go-pg/pg/v9"
)

type DataItem struct{
    tableName struct{} `pg:"some_table"`

    SomeID    string    `pg:"some_id,pk"`
    SomeData  string    `pg:"some_data"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `pg:"updated_at"`
}

type PostgresStorage struct {
    db *pg.DB
}

func Connect(ctx context.Context, cfg Config) (*PostgresStorage, error) {
    db, err := database.Connect(ctx, ....)
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    return &PostgresStorage{db: db}, nil
}

func (p *PostgresStorage) deleteAll(ctx context.Context) error {
    model := DataItem{}

    _, err := p.db.ModelContext(ctx, &model).Delete()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("DELETE: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

And I get an error:

`pg: Update and Delete queries require Where clause (try WherePK)`

I need to delete all records with no conditions. `WherePK()` also doesn't have sence here as I don't pick records by primary key.

What should I put to `WHERE`?

Comment: Works. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as a good one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding.Where("TRUE") to your Delete() call(as @mkopriva mentioned in comments), you are effectively creating a WHERE clause that will always evaluate to true, matching all rows in the table. This allows you to delete all records without specifying any specific conditions.

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
package storage

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/go-pg/pg/v9"
)

type DataItem struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"some_table"`

    SomeID    string    `pg:"some_id,pk"`
    SomeData  string    `pg:"some_data"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `pg:"updated_at"`
}

type PostgresStorage struct {
    db *pg.DB
}

func Connect(ctx context.Context, cfg Config) (*PostgresStorage, error) {
    db, err := database.Connect(ctx, ....)
    if err != nil {
        // ...
    }

    return &PostgresStorage{db: db}, nil
}

func (p *PostgresStorage) deleteAll(ctx context.Context) error {
    model := DataItem{}

    _, err := p.db.ModelContext(ctx, &model).Where("TRUE").Delete()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("DELETE: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the boolean constant `true` as the sole conditional expression, i.e.

```sql
DELETE FROM ... WHERE true;
```

I'm not 100% sure what the `go-pg` method call for that would look like but probably something like this:

```golang
p.db.ModelContext(ctx, &model).Where("?", true).Delete()
```